# passing shell script file name as an command line argument java -jar /test.sh and gives me error Error: Unable to access jarfile /test.sh

Tags: bash, shell-script, path

```
java -jar /test.sh --name trigger

Error: Unable to access jarfile /test.sh
```

test.sh file contains

```
#!/bin/sh
jar_name="-Dspring.config.location=application-test.properties somejarFileVersion_1.0" 
echo ${jar_name}
```

Comment: Is it really at `/test.sh` or did you mean to do `./test.sh`?

Comment: In both the ways I tried to execute with /test.sh or ./test.sh and throws error

Comment: Well where is test.sh?

Comment: running (trying to run) a shell script via `java -jar` seems a bit odd. Is it really supposed to work?

Comment: test.sh contains 
#!/bin/sh
jar_name="-Dspring.config.location=application-test.properties TriggerTransformation-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
echo ${jar_name}

Comment: Yes but where is it on your filesystem.  Also as @ilkkachu points out I'm not sure if it's even supposed to work.  But if test.sh is in `/home/venkata/project/test.sh` for example and you are currently in `/home/venkata` you need to use a full or relative path to point to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two problems there.

1. java tries to open the jar file named "test.sh". But that file is not a jar, its a shell script. What you want is the *output* of that shell script to be used as the jarfile name. so you Would need to do it like this:

```
java -jar $(bash ./test.sh) --name trigger
```

2. your script does not generate a valid jar file name either. It prints out an option for java and the jar file name. you need to take the `-D....` stuff out and put them in your inital command.